# How to validate Bearer Access Token using Identity Server 3 in Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver3

I added all the configuration for using IdentityServer 3 (Implicit Flow) in Asp.Net Core 2.1 for Bearer Token Authentication as:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://demo.identity.abc.com/identity/"; // Identity Server 3                    

                options.ApiName = "Test_Api"; // scope

                options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;
            });
        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            // IS3 does not include the api name/audience - hence the extra scope check
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(ScopePolicy.Create("Test_Api")));
        })
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddAuthorization();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
          options.Filters.Add(new Filter1());
       }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
       services.AddCors(); 
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {                     

        app.UseCors(policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();               
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error with details
`You must either set Authority or IntrospectionEndpoint`. 
From WebApi 2.0, the authority is working fine